# Creating custom contextmenu

Tags: .net, winforms, contextmenu, popupmenu

I have a v simple dialog box that I would like to display as a context menu.

I can catch the right click and show it as a modal dialog with no borders, if possible I would like it to look properly like the windows context menu (bar on lhs, blue border) - is there a way of doing this automatically to collect user desktop settings, (needs to work for both XP, Vista)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a context menu control in your Visual Studio toolbox. Use that.

If you need to display a dialog box on right click without border, that's possible too. As you said, catch the right click even and ShowModal. Also, you can get rid of the border by setting the 'BorderStyle' property of the dialog box to 'None'.